# Save Parse object which has User as Reference

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a **Parse** object with a User as pointer, but I'm getting this error :

> Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be
>   saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp":

Here is my code :

```
 var Post : PFObject?
    var objectid : String?

 let query = PFQuery(className: "Feed")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectid!) {
        (post: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && post != nil {
            self.Post = post
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
func comment() {

let Comment = PFObject(className:"Comments")
        Comment["Text"] = CommentField.text
        Comment.setObject(Post!, forKey: "Post") // 
        Comment["User"] = PFUser.currentUser()!
        Comment.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                self.CommentField.text = ""
                self.Refresh()
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
}
```

First I'm trying to retrieve the concerning Post from Parse, and when the User wants to comment, I'm creating this comment object and saving it, the post object has User as reference

[image]

Comment: Well... How are you authenticating people in your app? Did you enable Parse's automatic user functionality?

Comment: Have you enabled anonymous users with [PFUser enableAutomaticUser]; See more here https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users

Comment: I don't have a problem with the current user, I have an issue when saving other objects with pointer of other users

Comment: For someone who want an answer ! I used cloud function with a master key to do the required save.